# Using lower inequality to establish an equality in L^1 norm

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying for a qualifying exam. I came across the following problem that I cannot solve.

Let $f, g∈L^1(\mathbb{R})$.  Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $(T_{n}f) =f(x−n)$.  Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}‖T_nf+g‖_1=‖f‖_1+‖g‖_1$.

What I've been able to show is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||T_{n}f - f||=0$. Therefore, I have that for limsup inequality holds in the "$\leq$" direction. Perhaps Fatou's Lemma may help, however I'm not sure how to unravel the lower bound:

$ \int \liminf_{n \to \infty} |T_{n} f + g| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int  |T_{n} f + g| $

Comment: The claim $\|T_nf-f\|_1\to0$ you are making stands in contradiction to what you are trying to prove - and is also not true.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes. I've confused this with $\lim_{t \to 0} ||f(x+t) -f(x)|| = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,

$$ \|T_n f + g\| \le \|T_n f \| + \|g\| = \|f\| + \|g\|,$$

thus one direction

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}  \|T_n f + g\|  \le \|f\| + \|g\|$$

is simple. On the other hand, for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $N>0$ so that

$$\tag{1} \int_{-N}^N |f| \ge \| f\| - \epsilon, \ \ \int_{-N}^N |g| \ge \|g\| -\epsilon.$$

Let

$$ f_N = \begin{cases} f & |x| \le N, \\ 0 & |x|>N.\end{cases}$$

and similar for $g_N$. Then

\begin{align*}
\| T_n f_N + g_N\| &= \| T_n f_N - T_n f + T_n f + g_N-g +g\| \\
&\le \|T_n (f_N-f)\| + \|T_n f+ g\| + \|g-g_N\|\\
&\le \|T_n f+ g\| + 2\epsilon. 
\end{align*}

Now whenever $n>2N$, $T_n f_N$ and $g_N$ has disjoint support, thus by (1).
$$\|T_n f_N + g_N\| = \|T_n f_N\| + \|g_N\| = \|f_N\| + \| g_N\| \ge \|f\| + \|g\| - 2\epsilon.$$

Hence

$$ \|T_n f+ g\| \ge \|f\| + \|g\| - 4\epsilon$$

whenever $n \ge 2N$. Thus

$$ \liminf_{n\to \infty}\|T_n f+ g\| \ge \|f\| + \|g\|.$$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Could you explain why $f_{N}, g_{N}$ have disjoint support?

Comment: No  its $T_n f_N$ and $g_N$ which has disjoint support when $n$ is large. Since $f_N$ and $g_N$ both have support in $[-N, N]$ and $T_n$ acts as translation. @bivouac_tenure